# Usar regex para reemplazar todas las ocurrencias con CASE_INSENSITIVE (sin considerar mayúsculas y minúsculas)

Tags: java, regex

Trato de hacer un método que busque y reemplace palabras utilizando expresiones regulares. El punto es que debo poder buscar y reemplazar la palabra sin importar si tiene letras mayúsculas o no. Éste es el código que llevo:

```
public String reemplazar(String cadena,JFrame frame){
    StringBuffer reemplazar = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer buscar = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer respuesta = new StringBuffer();

    DlgReemplazar dlgReemplazar = new DlgReemplazar(
        frame, true, buscar, reemplazar, constantesGUI.REEMPLAZAR, respuesta
    );
    dlgReemplazar.setVisible(true);

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(buscar.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(cadena);

    if (mat.find() == true) {
        cadena = cadena.replaceAll(
            String.valueOf(buscar), String.valueOf(reemplazar)
        );
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encontro el texto");
    }      
    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: Hola @user3912930. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Me imagino que `buscar` es una palabra ingresada por el usuario, y que hay que escapar los caracteres especiales primero antes de reemplazar... Y por otro lado, no deberías agregarle `\b` antes y después para que busque palabras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El primer punto a corregir es que hay que escapar los caracteres especiales que pueda haber en la variable. Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa `[hola]`, entiendo que debería buscar ese texto literal, y no sólo uno de esos 4 caracteres.

Para obtener un patrón literal a partir de un string se utiliza [Pattern.quote()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).

```java
String patronBuscado = Pattern.quote(buscar.toString());
```

- No haría falta escaparlo si se usa el modificador [Pattern.LITERAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL), aunque personalmente prefiero hacerlo sin este modificador para que sea más claro o permita sólo escapar una parte del patrón.

Y lo mismo aplica para el reemplazo, donde deberías usar [Matcher.quoteReplacement()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)).

```java
String patronReemplazo = Matcher.quoteReplacement(reemplazar.toString());
```

---

Ahora sí, vayamos a lo principal. Como habrás visto, [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) no acepta modificadores como `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, ni un `Pattern`, sólo Strings.

Hay 3 formas de reemplazar sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas.

1. Pasando el modificador en línea como `(?i)` dentro de la expresión regular:

   ```java
   cadena = cadena.replaceAll( "(?i)" + patronBuscado, patronReemplazo);
   ```
2. Utilizar [Matcher.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) sobre una expresión regular compilada:

   ```java
   Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(patronBuscado, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   Matcher mat = pat.matcher(cadena);
   cadena = mat.replaceAll(patronReemplazo);
   ```
3. Alternativamente se pueden utilizar los métodos [Matcher.appendReplacement()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) y [Matcher.appendTail()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuffer)) para ir reemplazando con un StringBuffer y tener mayor control sobre cada uno de los reemplazos. Sin embargo, esto es innecesario si simplemente se quieren reemplazar todas las ocurrencias por el mismo valor.

---

Por útlimo, hay que tener en cuenta que `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` sólo trabaja en el rango de ASCII. Si quisieras también reemplazar acentos, deberías agregar [Pattern.UNICODE_CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) (o el modificador en línea `(?iu)`):

```java
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(patronBuscado, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

---

**Código:**

```java
String cadena = "Respuesta de SO en inglés";

StringBuffer buscar = new StringBuffer("EN INGLÉS");
String patronBuscado = Pattern.quote(buscar.toString());

StringBuffer reemplazar = new StringBuffer("en español");
String patronReemplazo = Matcher.quoteReplacement(reemplazar.toString());

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(patronBuscado, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(cadena);

if (mat.find()) {
    cadena = mat.replaceAll(patronReemplazo);
    System.out.println("Resultado: " + cadena);
} else {
    System.out.println("No se encontro el texto");
}
```

**Demo:**

<kbd>[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8Rwq4H)</kbd>